# Restrict particular apps from syncing depending on current WiFi connection

Tags: wi-fi, sync

Is there an app that will allow full sync functions to only occur when connected to particular white-listed WiFi and / or **keep selected accounts from syncing when on other away / public / non white-listed WiFi routers?**

Example being, when I am on my trusted WiFi connections to have full sync rights allowing Gmail and Facebook as well as other apps to function normally but when on a WiFi not white-listed only allow browsing or particular apps to access and sync?

I imagine this would be a firewall function however have yet to find one that distinguishes multiple WiFi connections from each other.
If an app like this does not exist what code would be a good start to review and develop such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to realize that for "specific apps to sync". But using an [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app like [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), you should be able to globally switch sync on/off depending on whether you are connected to a specific WiFi. Basic structure for *Tasker:*

1. Create a Task, name it e.g. "SafeWifiTask", and have it switch Sync on.
   (you can also add other jobs to this task which you want to perform on a "safe connection", all in this task)
2. Optionally, create an opposite task to switch Sync off
3. Create a Profile with the condition "WiFi Connected", and select your "safe network's" SSID. Assign it the "SafeWifiTask" created above, and optionally the "opposite task" as exit task.
4. Repeat step 3 for other "safe network conditions" (*Tasker* doesn't know about an OR condition on profiles)

I've made the "exit task" optional in my example. The reason behind it is: If no exit task exists, *Tasker* automatically restores the "before" conditions, so you might be able to do without exit tasks.

Comment: I will definitely investigate this method and keep you updated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad to help! Alternatives to *Tasker* are listed e.g. in my App-Lists on [Automation (Profile Switching and more)](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=178) – just in case Tasker proves a little too complex (took me ~3 days to find my way into Tasker, and I've bought it straight away then, never regretted it – but YMMV ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since your question was only 1/2 answered I wanted to complete it. There is an app that will allow you to enable and disable specific apps from syncing. It can also start and stop the syncing process. The app is called [Synker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afterhoursdevelopers.android.synker) and the unlock will run you $1.99 but it is well worth it to keep your info secure and to help reduce distractions.

Comment: Thank you. it is my intent to get both applications recommended and see if I can work them together to accomplish my goal I will keep you updated as soon as I am able.

Comment: Keep in the loop. I used this all the time when I was trying to be productive and I didn't want anything distracting me. If this works out for you please remember to click that this answer was useful. I;ve been trying to increase my rep on this site at least for tasker tasks.

Comment: I have purchased both apps, my research shows the way to handle this is to have the auto sync off as the default setting and use Tasker to force sync at intervals using Synker Profiles to control what apps gets synchronized and what wifi networks to connect to when in range of Taskers list of approved wifi via ssid or mac. I will post an update when I figure out the correct recipe. Both suggestions seem to be winners.

Comment: If you need more help feel free to keep asking question. Once you're satisfied please don't forget to mark my question as being right.

Comment: Actually I am trying to figure proper protocol in this matter. Both programs are needed for the function I was looking for. I want to up vote both suggestions for helping give me proper direction (and i shall as soon as my "rep" score allows). But regarding actual steps, and completed solution should I write up the procedure and mark it as the answer that  worked?

Comment: I don't feel it is needed. I found that once both are installed and people the Synker interface it is fairly easy to understand what you need to do to achieve most taskers. I'm glad to hear it worked for you.